# Handling field null values in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3, null

I've wrote a plugin and when I was tested it I found a plugin's case of use that it has to handle with null values. I've had some research and doesnt found much about it in PyQGIS3 documentation, but I read about `NULL` from `qgis.core` and write the code below:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject, NULL

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('My_Layer_Name')[0]
selection = layer.selectedFeatures()
n_sel = layer.selectedFeatureCount()

if n_sel > 0:
    layer.startEditing()
    for feature in selection:
        pos = feature['offset_quad']
        if pos == NULL:
            pos = 0
        else:
            pos = int(feature['offset_quad'])
    # do some stuf here
```

I'd like to know if there is a better "pythonic" way to do this test for null values.

Comment: Have you tried if pos == None? What sort of feature data are you working with? Not all data types support null (None) values.

Comment: Python syntax is `if pos is None`. I Think your code is ok, easy to understand. (You could shorten it with `pos = 0 if pos is None else int(pos)`)

Comment: @MichaelStimson, thanks for your comment. As a pyqgis newbie, I've already read that has some difference between none and null values in python, but I need to read more. So, I've tried your suggestion and works fine, thanks.

Comment: @BERA, I do `print('null') if pos is None else print('not null')` and returns `not null`. I'm missing something? I liked this way of shorten conditionals, where I can find some docs to learn more about it?

Comment: I have encountered an issue with this.  In a case where `pos` returns `{QVariant}NULL` the statement `if pos != None` evaluates to False but `if pos is not None` returns True.  Apparently a `{QVariant}NULL` *equals* `None` although it is *not* `None`.  This creates an issue in variance with PEP8.

Comment: Reference: https://woostuff.wordpress.com/2013/08/31/qgis-2-0-dealing-with-null-values-in-pyqgis/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess a somewhat more pythonic method could be to use:

```
if not pos:
```

So something like:

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('My_Layer_Name')[0]
selection = layer.selectedFeatures()
n_sel = layer.selectedFeatureCount()

if n_sel > 0:
    for feature in selection:
        pos = feature['tesr']
        if not pos:
            pos = 0
        else:
            pos = int(feature['tesr'])
```

Comment: Thanks @Joseph. Following your suggestion and @BERA way of shorten, I code this: `pos = 0 if not pos else int(pos)` and works fine.

Comment: Great answer. Always good to remember 'going Pythonic' can avert many package-specific problems - like what exactly the Null (NULL?) value is in QGIS anyways..

Comment: `not pos` evaluates to True if pos is `0`, an empty string or or or. This is not what you wanted but rather a bug! OP's original `pos == NULL` is actually the right approach.